# Fetching fails in NextJS on a local api

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, fetch

My co-worker has developed a backend application using spring boot, for some reason, I only can get api when our two computers are connected to a same hotspot. In a browser or postman, i enter the other computer's api and port and I can get get the data from REST Api
But when I'm on application and I use Axios or either fetch() for fetching,

[fetch method responds
like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npzfn.png)

[and Axios responds like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjMD3.png)

How to fix this?

PS: [here is the temporary code for fetching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Yvn.png)

Comment: Its doesn't seem to be a frontend problem

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it's a cors authorization problem, we need more informations

try to enableCors for the resetApi application

Answer (score -2):

Try to enable CORS,

The first method using axios.

Your Express app needs to use CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). Add the following to your server file:

```
// This should already be declared in your API file
var app = express();

// ADD THIS
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Besides, for fetch method you need to add `async` and `await`.

Comment: OP's server is Spring Boot, not Express